# ASP.NET and objects

Tags: asp.net, oop, object

Let's say I have a class Person, with a string[] nickNames, where Person can have 0 or more nicknames stored.  I want to create an asp.net page where a user can go and add/edit/delete nicknames.
Question is- how to i persist the Person object between postbacks?  I query the DB and create the object then display it on a form, but then the user has the option to edit/delete fields of that object.. once the page is displayed with the fields of Person, how do I update that object with the changes the user made, to store to db?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well if your Person Object is serializable you could store it in ViewState and if not, you could stick it in Session, but it sounds like you might have a general lack of understanding about Data Persistance in general

Depending on your implementation, and whether you're coding this all by hand or using the built in DataSource/DataAdapter controls, theres a bunch of ways to do it.

You could have a look at some basic ASP.NET/ADO.NET Tutorials to point you in the right direction

http://aspnet101.com/aspnet101/tutorials.aspx?id=17

Comment: hmm, so if the Person object expands to typical contact information- address, name, etc., maybe 20 fields.. would it be preferable to serialize the object and store in ViewState, or to put it in Session?

I will be using the built in SQL data source / adapter controls and have looked into databinding but since this is not being displayed in a gridview, and also since they will be able to add additional nicknames, i don't think I can use databinding

Answer (score 0):

Query the object it again (you could store it in a session variable but that doesn't scale), gather and apply changes from user upon postback.

Comment: You'd be surprised how sometimes stating the obvious helps to get someone unstuck.

Comment: ocdecio the "be nice" comment was aimed at Will. No point scaring the new guys away with sarcasm :)

Comment: @Eoin - well said. We've all been there one day,